# Get network information in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I've been using the methods `OutboundBitsPerSecond`and  `MegabytesUsed` which are in the `Windows.Networking.Connectivity;` namespace. These methods return `null` when i call them and although I have had some networking data back e.g. the router name, encryption type etc, I have been unable to get any statistical data e.g. `dataPlanStatus.OutboundBitsPerSecond;` and `dataPlan.DataPlanUsage.MegabytesUsed`

Why is this and there is another alternative way. I am trying to work out the current download speed. Would it be possible to time a download of a paticular file to work out the speed and if so which is the best way to go about it.